# Excel, extracting different words from text cell, depending on conditions (IFS, MID, SEARCH)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In one column I have names of incidents, often with hostnames. They are different, but have similar patterns. I wanted to extract them to another column. At first I was using this formula:

```
=MID(C5, SEARCH("nuk*", c5), 8)
```

It was fine for hosts beginning with "nuk"

However I wanted to make a formula, which will be looking for specific hostname e.g. "nuk", "mon", "tlx" etc.

I tried this one:

```
IF(SEARCH("nuk", C5), MID(C5, SEARCH("nuk*", c5), 8), IF(SEARCH("mon", C5), MID(C5, SEARCH("mon*", c5), 8)))
```

This one gave me result only for first condition and for the second one always `#VALUE!`.

I have tried IFS also but ot gave me the same result as previous.

Do you know where am I making mistake?

Comment: Would you mind providing some sample data so that others can more easily assist?

Comment: Give this a try: `=MID(C5,MIN(SEARCH({"nuk","mon","tlx"},C5&"nukmontlx")),8)`

Answer (score 0):

This formula will return the position of either of your 3 choices.

`=IFERROR(FIND("nuk";A1);IFERROR(FIND("tlx";A1);IFERROR(FIND("mon";A1);"NoMatch")))`

[image]

You can modify this to extract sub-strings with MID function.

Answer (score 0):

If at first you don't succeed, try again:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(MID(C5,SEARCH("nuk*",C5),8),MID(C5,SEARCH("mon*",C5),8)),"")
```